# Can't figure out what this MatLab error is telling me

Tags: matlab

So I have this code here that attempts to load in an excel file of exam grades which is a 35x5 set of data, and calculate the mean test score of each student (35 students, 5 tests each). It then is supposed to spit out the letter grade earned by each student based on their average score.

```
%65    P
%Penna Garrett

%Exam Grades part 2

%Loading the Exam Scores from Excell
grades = xlsread ('Exam_Grades_Data_Part2')
%Don't need to do display because xlsread throws it into command window


%Letter grade earned based on this scale of average test scores:
%0-59 = E
%60-69 = D
%70-75 = C
%76-79 = C+
%80-85 = B
%86-89 = B+
%90-100 = A

%To Calculate the average for all rows I will use a loop function
temp = size(grades)

%Here is my 'for' function
loopend = size(grades,1)

for i=1: loopend
    average(i) = mean(grades(i,1:5));

    if (average(i) <= 59)
        letter{i} = 'E' ;
    elseif (average(i) <= 69)
        letter{i} = 'D' ;
    elseif (average(i) <= 75)
        letter{i} = 'C' ;
    elseif (average(i) <= 79)
        letter{i} = 'C+' ;
    elseif (average(i) <= 85)
        letter{i} = 'B' ;
    elseif (average(i) <= 89)
        letter{i} = 'B+' ;
    elseif (89 < average(i) <= 100)
        letter{i} = 'A' ;
    end
end


display('Hopefully you have recieved the grade you wanted. If not, I may see you next year! Dr. P')
display (letter)
```

I can't for the life of me figure out the error I am getting.
It says in the command window:

Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object.

Error in S65_Garrett_Penna_07 (line 42)

letter{i} = 'A' ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have the variable "letter" in the workspace as a non-cell datatype (like a double). You should probably initialize this variable as cell someplace above your for loop,

```
letter = {};
```